# Get list of changes in Windows Sync Center

Tags: windows, sync

In Windows Sync Center, is it possible to get a history of what files have changed/added/removed after a sync has been completed?

As per why I want to do this .. see my new question [Sync Windows folders with remote server and log changes that are made](https://superuser.com/q/1244101/5253)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Unfortunately Windows does not log the files that are modified as part of a synchronization operation.

You are alerted to files that *fail* to sync, which results in partial exposure to files that are involved in sync operations, but obviously this falls short of your stated request.

While I've not personally done so, you could enable [audit logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070(v=ws.11).aspx), but this approach can impact I/O performance *and* generate a lot of logged events unrelated to sync operations.

Comment: That's frustrating because Windows must know somewhere

Comment: @PeterM Agreed; however having come in contact with information and actually *recording* it are two different affairs. The same applies to logging files accessed on a server. Yes, Windows knows about it, but doesn't log any of it.

Comment: Maybe my real question should be what alternatives are there that can show me a list of changes.

Comment: If you do post another question to ask that, I encourage you to provide some background as to why you are looking for a log. As this present post may demonstrate, asking about your [proposed solution instead of the actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445) can lead to frustration for you and those answering.

Comment: However I am not sure how to phrase a new question without sounding like a request for a recommendation for a solution.  But I'll give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: See my new question that I referenced above.