# Sync Windows folders with remote server and log changes that are made

Tags: windows, sync, offline-files

I work remotely as part of a distributed team working on a project.  Our project files are stored on a server share that I access via a VPN.

Currently I use Offline Files to maintain a local copy of the current project state.  However [it appears I can't get a list of changes that have occurred between syncs](https://superuser.com/q/1244009/5253).  But that is crucial for me.

Case in point, yesterday I spent several hours comparing lists of Bills of Materials with equipment that was specified on the project drawings and discovered lots of discrepancies.  So I wrote up an email listing the differences and sent it out.  Today I find out (by accident) that the BOM files I referred to yesterday have now moved around and newer ones had magically appeared in a new sub-directory.  Obviously someone (working remotely in a different location) realized that the newer files were not on the server and "cleaned" things up overnight.

**How can I keep copies of these files offline, be able to sync them, and have a history of all changes made by each sync?** I would like the sync to work like the built-in Offline Files/Windows Sync Center.

As for the log history, I am looking for a simple list of files/directories that have been added/deleted/changed. This is critical.

I don't have control over the server. I can only make software changes on my end. I'm running Windows 10 on my machine.

---

BTW suggesting some sort of repository system on the server side is *not* an option.  Don't even ask why not.

Comment: I have edited your question in an effort to make it more succinct and avoid requesting a software recommendation. Please rollback if you don't feel I honored the spirit of your request. Further, I suggest you shorten (or eliminate) paragraph #3. Simply stating your working on a distributed project and need to see changes to files should suffice. The final paragraph is probably redundant too.

Comment: @Twisty I don't mind the edits but that 3rd paragraph is a bit of a guilty rant :D

Comment: What is the nature of the files you're keeping offline that necessitates seeing what files have been modified at each sync? Do you have any influence over what sort of files are used to track the changes in your project? I ask because what you are doing (working with shared data as a team) is very common, but *using separate documents to track individual tasks/elements/etc* seems unusual.

Comment: @PeterM I do realize the purpose of the 3rd paragraph...for you. :)  It makes your question longer, which will result in fewer people sticking with you to the end. Keep in my SU is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Keeping the paragraph isn't the end of the world in this case though!!

Comment: @Twisty I just need to get lists of what has changed not how they have changed.  The Collection of files includes everything from images, autocad drawings binary blobs all the way through to simple text files.

Comment: You're doing this with [offline files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755136%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), correct?

Comment: @Twisty yes .. offline

Comment: Here's a screen shot of a Robocopy log file showing the new files that were copied over https://i.imgur.com/PIlOfNw.png & here's one showing the "newer" files being copied over https://i.imgur.com/5KyQXF8.png. Robocopy is built into Windows & native to Windows so go to command prompt type in `robocopy /?` & press enter—it is NOT 3rd party if you were wondering so seems like a perfect job for Robocopy to me if you're not stuck on the offline files functionality which I assume works very similary behind the scenes perhaps to keep offline copies available when offline and two way or one way sync.

Comment: I second Robocopy. But if this is used it will be critical that 1) Offline files be disabled, 2) which requires the local copy of the share to be stored in a separate path, which 3) will break any links to file paths if used (e.g. In one project file to link to another). Buyer beware!

Comment: @McDonald's as per Twisty's comment it seems like Robocopy will introduce more negatives than positives

Comment: @PeterM You will obviously need to setup a test and do a test run to confirm that this sort of solution would suffice for your need. It's true that there may be some gotchas based on your environment, requirements, etc. so if you decide to give it a shot to test and confirm maybe on a small scale system to see how it goes, that would be recommended regardless. It may be that the Windows offline is more appropriate in your setup but only you can test and decide this I suppose. I use it a lot in environments I support and it suffices in those case—don't want to over analyze your question though.

Comment: That suggestion was merely a suggestion and thus I left as a comment rather than an answer but it may or may not be helpful in your case. If you decided to test out the functionality and have questions, etc. afterwards; shoot me a note back if you wish.